# How to show Options tab for new meeting in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to set up voting options/buttons for my new meeting. Some searches on the 'net mention that [voting options can be found in the "Options" tab](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-and-send-a-voting-poll-in-an-email-message-HP010355562.aspx) of the New Meeting window. However, it seems there is no "Options" tab in my Outlook.

My tabs:
[image]

I've looked through "Customize Ribbon", but don't see the "Options" tab nor voting options there either.

[image]

How can I go about finding the voting options?

Comment: Worth noting is that if you have Microsoft Lync within your place, you can do polls and many other miscellaneous things in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: Outlook 2013, not 2010**

Looking through, I don't know if it's possible to allow voting options when scheduling a *meeting*, however, it is there when I simply create an *email*. Most resources that I have found reference the availability within email creation, not meeting creation.

[image]

[(Bigger image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wejfO.png)

Comment: Strange to see voting not included in meeting invites though, seems like a practical spot for it..

Answer (score 0):

Click File->Properties to see Voting and Tracking Options, "use voting buttons"